# duplicate entry: META-INF/ when build .apk. with gradle plugin 3.0.0. Exclude not applicable here

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

> Before asking this question I searched for an answer

In short: problem appears with the latest version of Gradle plugin for Android Studio version 3.0.0.

If I use previous version of Gradle plugin (2.3.3) Studio builds .apk  without problem/

Error text:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':stockManagment:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForNextDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException:
> >     java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/

All solutions found at SO and other sites recommend using 'exclude', but these problems usually appear with 'META-INF/somefile.txt' , not 'META-INF/' directory itself.

I can't exclude whole 'META-INF/' directory, but I exclude common files inside this dir (licence, dependencies, etc.).

Here are my build.gradle files.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    signingConfigs {
        release_config {
            keyAlias 'stock_managment'
            keyPassword '********'
            storeFile file('../stockmanagment_keystore.jks')
            storePassword '********'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release_config
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "next"
    productFlavors {
        next {
            applicationId "com.stockmanagment.next.app"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 47
            versionName '2.0.17'
            dimension "next"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

def support = '26.1.0'
def dagger = '2.11'
def butterKnife = "8.8.1"
def moxy = "1.5.3"
def robolectric = "3.0"

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '../libs')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
    implementation("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    }
    implementation("com.android.support:design:$support") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    }
    implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    }
    implementation("com.android.support:preference-v7:$support") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    }
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnife"
    implementation("com.android.support:support-v4:$support") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    }
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnife"
    implementation "com.arello-mobile:moxy:$moxy"
    implementation "com.arello-mobile:moxy-app-compat:$moxy"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectric"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:$robolectric"
    annotationProcessor "com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:$moxy"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker:colorpicker-library:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
    implementation 'com.nikhilpanju.recyclerviewenhanced:recyclerviewenhanced:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.johnkil.print:print:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.tiromansev:Android-Prefs-Wrapper:0.2.2'
    implementation 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.5.0'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15'
    implementation 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.tiromansev:Android-Permission-Manager:0.2.7'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.12'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
    implementation 'com.github.tiromansev:Android-File-Dialog:0.2.4'
    implementation 'com.github.tiromansev:Android-Scan-Barcode:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.tiromansev:FloatingActionButton:1.6.7'
    implementation 'com.github.tiromansev:AndroidTreeView:0.0.1'
}

task copyLocales << {
    copy {
        from 'src/main/res/values-ru/strings.xml'
        into 'src/main/res/values-uk'
    }
    copy {
        from 'src/main/res/values-ru/strings.xml'
        into 'src/main/res/values-be'
    }
    copy {
        from 'src/main/res/values/strings.xml'
        into 'src/main/res/values-en'
    }
}

preBuild.dependsOn copyLocales

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == "lint") {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You may use `exclude 'META-INF/*'` Did you run `gradlew clean build`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with Apache POI library which was included as .jar file from /libs directory. This .jar contained empty /META-INF directory which was the cause of the problem.

Deleting this empty directory from .jar file resolved the problem. If /META-INF is not empty it also works ok. With Gradle plugin 2.3.3 building .apk works smoothly even with empty /META_INF directory.

So, the combination of Gradle plugin 3.0.0 and empty /META_INF directory in .jar creates the problem.

UPDATE 27.11.2017
This bug has been fixed in the current version